# Find MacLaurin polynomial of integral

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have not the slightest idea how to begin with the following problem. My first thought is to integrate it before trying to find the MacLaurin polynomial, but I don't know if that is possible. Here is the problem:

> Let $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{-3t^4} dt$
>
> Find the MacLaurin polynomial of degree 5 for $F(x)$.

Answer to first part here

> Use this polynomial to estimate the value of $\int_0^{0.14} e^{-3x^4}dx$x

Answer to second part here

I am certain that, I am able to understand part 1, I can answer part 2. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that you can integrate the Maclaurin series term-by-term.

Comment: By this do you mean that I should use the fact that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and integrate each term in the summation term-by-term?

Comment: Yes, of course you would first substitute $-3x^4$ for $x$.

Comment: Does it not matter that $-3t^4$ is what the exponent is? I'm confused on how it transforms into $-3x^4$.

Comment: Replacing $x$ with $-3x^4$ in your formula gives the Maclaurin series for $e^{-3x^4}$, which you can then integrate.

Comment: So I would integrate like the following? $\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-3x^4)^n}{n!}$ I'm not sure how to integrate this, being as it is a summation and the integral is not definite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26230/discussion-between-cremedekhan-and-torsionsquid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first,
$$
e^{-3t^4} = 1 - 3t^4 + \text{powers of $t$ greater than $4$}.
$$
So,
$$
\int_0^x e^{-3t^4}dt = x - \frac35 x^5 + \text{powers of $x$ greater than $5$}.
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{0.14} e^{-3t^4}dt \approx 0.14 - \frac35 (0.14)^5
$$

Answer (score 0):

If a series converges uniformly, then its integral is equal to the series of the integrals. On any interval, the series for the exponential converges uniformly.